# Locally install a man page

Tags: shell, man

I'm trying to make a script to locally install in a designated folder a personnal man page.

I've tried changing the manpath, but this does not work..

My only objective is to let the user use :

```bsh
$ man mproject
```

I have a mproject.3 file in the same directory, so I tried appending '.' (both litteraly and with absolute path) to manpath..

Is this at all possible ?

EDIT : OS is :

Linux **** 5.5.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 18 Mar 2020 08:40:35 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT : hierarchy

```
| base_folder
   |--- man
   |     |--- man3
   |           |--- mproject.3
   |--- files
   |...
```

`$MANPATH=<path-to-base_folder/man>:`

`$MANPATH` was set using command

`MANPATH=$(pwd):$MANPATH`

while inside `base-folder/man` directory

EDIT : strace

```
execve("/usr/bin/man", ["man", "mproject"], 0x7ffc177c7998 /* 46 vars */) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/tls/haswell/x86_64/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/tls/haswell/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/tls/haswell", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/tls/x86_64/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/tls/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/tls", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/haswell/x86_64/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/haswell/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/haswell", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/x86_64/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/man-db/x86_64", 0x7ffc16c420c0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libmandb-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libman-2.9.1.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libpipeline.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libpipeline.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libgdbm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libgdbm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/man-db/libseccomp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libseccomp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oliver/.manpath", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/man_db.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/home/oliver/.cabal/bin/less", 0x7ffc16c42af0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/bin/less", 0x7ffc16c42af0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/env/less", 0x7ffc16c42af0) = -1 ENOTDIR (N'est pas un dossier)
stat("/usr/local/bin/less", 0x7ffc16c42af0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/less", 0x7ffc16c42af0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/less", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=179664, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr_FR.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr_FR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/man-db.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/home/oliver/.cabal/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.cabal/bin/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.cabal/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.cabal/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/bin/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/env/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOTDIR (N'est pas un dossier)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/home/oliver/.ghcup/env/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOTDIR (N'est pas un dossier)
stat("/usr/local/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/jvm/default/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/jvm/default/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/man", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=115296, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/site_perl/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/site_perl/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/man", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=115296, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/vendor_perl/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/vendor_perl/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/man", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=115296, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/core_perl/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/bin/core_perl/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/Fac/L3 Info 2019-2020/Preparation/S5/ARO/AMPL/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/Fac/L3 Info 2019-2020/Preparation/S5/ARO/AMPL/ampl/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/Fac/L3 Info 2019-2020/Preparation/S5/ARO/AMPL/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/Fac/L3 Info 2019-2020/Preparation/S5/ARO/AMPL/ampl/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/BAL/2019/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/BAL/2019/CSV/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/BAL/2019/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("~/Documents/BAL/2019/CSV/share/man", 0x7ffc16c42a30) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
stat("/usr/man", 0x7ffc16c429a0)        = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
stat("/usr/share/man/zh_TW", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/ja", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/id", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/pl.ISO8859-2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/pt", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/da.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/da", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/sv", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/de.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/hu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/it", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/sl", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/ru", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/pl", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/de", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/it.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/es", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/pt_BR", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/ru.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/ko", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/zh_CN", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/zh_Hant", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/jp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/ru.KOI8-R", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/nb_NO", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/tr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/it.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/uk", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/sr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/nl", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/da.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/cs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man/fr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/local/share/man", "../man", 4095) = 6
lstat("/usr/local/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/man", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1/man1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/index.db", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr/man1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/man/fr/index.db", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/man1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/index.db", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/man/oldlocal/index.db", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/man/index.db", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/mann", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr/man8", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man8", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr/man3", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man3", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man2", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr/man5", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man5", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man4", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man6", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man/man7", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/man", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
Aucune entrée de manuel pour mproject
```

Comment: I've tried the absolute path also.. Do I need every section or just man3 ?

Comment: Please also show the value of `MANPATH` and tell where your man page is located. Are you sure your value of `MANPATH` is present for the `man` command?

Comment: Not sure about if the value is present. If I `echo $MANPATH`, I get the path I gave, however it does not seem to affect `man` command

Comment: Please add all information to the question. I suggest to show (or describe) how exactly you set the variable and how you call `man`. On my Ubuntu 19.10 MANPATH works as expected. Please add the information I requested in my previous comment. Without this information it is not possible to interpret the `strace` output.

Comment: I added the information to the question

Comment: Please show the exact unmodified commands you use for setting `MANPATH` and running `man mproject`. If you change the directory name to something like `path-to-base_folder` it does not match the `strace` output. Is there anything secret in your real directory path? If you only use `MANPATH=$(pwd):$MANPATH` without exporting it and without combining it with the `man` command like `MANPATH=$(pwd):$MANPATH man mproject`), `man` will not get this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `.` (the current directory) to `MANPATH` you should use the absolute path of the base directory which must contain a manual page hierarchy including sections like `man1` etc. If you use `.`, the `man` command would search in the current directory at the time when you run `man`, whatever that may be.

If your man page is `mproject.3` it should be in e.g. `/your/local/man/man3/mproject.3`, and you have to add `/your/local/man` to `MANPATH`.

It is sufficient to have subdirectories for the sections that contain manual pages. In your case you need only `man3`.

Note that section 3 implies that `mproject` is a library call. (See `man man`.)

Comment: I've tried adding that path as you said, but I still get `No man page for mproject`

Comment: I'm also aware for manual sections, it is a correct choice placing it in section 3

Comment: What is your OS? Add this to your question. On Linux you can use `strace -e trace=file man mproject` to see where it searches for man pages.

Comment: I've edited the question